# Command-line checkout results in 'upgrade working copy' prompt

Tags: command-line-interface, tortoisesvn

Using Tortoise SVN version 1.10.1, I have a batch file that checks out multiple (~20) Visual C# .NET projects from the SVN Server.

If I right-click on the project folder, the context menu contains 'SVN Upgrade working copy'. Until I do this, the overlay icons are not right and I will get complaints when I open the project in Visual Studio.

If I use the UI version of checkout, I use the default options for Checkout Depth, Revision, and dont-omit-externals. When I check out a project this way, the icons are correct and I am able to open the project normally in VS.

The command-line arguments are poorly documented for Tortoise; how do I use the command-line version of checkout that gives the same results as the UI version?

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted on the Tortoise user group and received a reply:

The command-line SVN.EXE being called by the batch file was an older application (v1.7) from Collabnet. I updated the batch file to use an explicit path to the correct Tortoise version of SVN.EXE  and it worked fine.